# How do you apply is.na to multiple columns in r

Tags: r, na

I want to do a very simple thing but more elegantly. see below.

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 4, 3))

x[1,] <- NA

x$X4 <- ifelse(is.na(X1) & is.na(X2) & is.na(X3), 1, 0)
```

Now I would like to do something like

```
x$X4 <- ifelse(is.na(X1, X2, X3), 1, 0)
```

Pretty easy right? Any help on that? Thx

*The real code I want to implement :*

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    sum = ifelse(is.na(X1) & is.na(X2) & is.na(X3) & is.na(X4) & is.na(Y), NA_real_, sum(X1, X2, X3, X4, na.rm = T))
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to look across the whole data set to find any values then:

```
    any(is.na(df))
    # This will return true
```

To get column sums:

```
    colSums(is.na(df))
```

You could also use purr to map over and get the sum of nas per column, but that is what the above is doing:

```
    map(df, ~sum(is.na(.)))
```

Just adapt the sum with mean in these instances.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
x$X4=ifelse(rowMeans(is.na(x))==1,1,0)

  X1 X2 X3 X4
1 NA NA NA  1
2  2  6 10  0
3  3  7 11  0
4  4  8 12  0
```

or `x$X4=as.integer(rowMeans(is.na(x))==1)`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much it works perfectly. If in addition if the condition is specified over a subset of columns it can be called by x[,var1:varz]